# Input type text next to submit, Y offset

Tags: html, css, text, input, submit

I have this code:

```
<div style='padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #777; width: 500px; height: 500px;'>
<div style='border: 1px solid #000; width: 260px; height: 26px;'>
    <form style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <input type='text'  style='margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-color: #F88; height: 26px; width: 200px'/><input type='submit' value=''  style='margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-color: #88F;  height: 26px; width: 60px'/>
    </form>
</div></div>
```

You can see the 2 inputs tags are directly after wach other in one line or else that break will create a space of course, annoyingly.
Anyway this is the result:

[image]

So what gives here ? Why are chrome and Safari behaving strange ?
I tried like everything, resetting border, margin and padding to 0 even line heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add `vertical-align:top` to the `input` elements. They are `inline` elements, therefore `vertical-align` will have an effect on them. It's worth noting that the default value of this property is `baseline`. Additionally, you should really be using CSS as opposed to inline styling.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtwNw/)

```
<div style='padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #777; width: 500px; height: 500px;'>
   <div style='border: 1px solid #000; width: 260px; height: 26px;'>
      <form style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
         <input type='text'  style='vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-color: #F88; height: 26px; width: 200px'/><input type='submit' value=''  style='vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background-color: #88F;  height: 26px; width: 60px'/>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks. I was just using the inline css to show this here.